# Error in building an android project successfully in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-intent

I'm having problems building an Android project even though I'm following a tutorial off youtube exactly as it describes. I'm getting a 'styles' error even though I've set the theme of the project to 'none'.

I've tried importing the appcombat v7 folder from the SDK into my project but the problem is still unresolved.

Here's the error:

```
[2016-06-23 04:16:56 - Yogi] D:\(W)-(A)-Eclipse Luna\Yogi\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2016-06-23 04:16:56 - Yogi] 

[2016-06-23 04:16:56 - Yogi] D:\(W)-(A)-Eclipse Luna\Yogi\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2016-06-23 04:16:56 - Yogi] 

[2016-06-23 04:16:56 - Yogi] D:\(W)-(A)-Eclipse Luna\Yogi\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2016-06-23 04:16:56 - Yogi] 

[2016-06-23 04:16:59 - Yogi] D:\(W)-(A)-Eclipse Luna\Yogi\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2016-06-23 04:16:59 - Yogi] 

[2016-06-23 04:16:59 - Yogi] D:\(W)-(A)-Eclipse Luna\Yogi\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2016-06-23 04:16:59 - Yogi] 

[2016-06-23 04:16:59 - Yogi] D:\(W)-(A)-Eclipse Luna\Yogi\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2016-06-23 04:16:59 - Yogi] 

[2016-06-23 04:17:07 - Yogi] D:\(W)-(A)-Eclipse Luna\Yogi\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2016-06-23 04:17:07 - Yogi] 

[2016-06-23 04:17:07 - Yogi] D:\(W)-(A)-Eclipse Luna\Yogi\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2016-06-23 04:17:07 - Yogi] 

[2016-06-23 04:17:07 - Yogi] D:\(W)-(A)-Eclipse Luna\Yogi\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
```

Eclipse is properly configured with ADT and SDK directory in preferences. My SDK is installed with Android 6 (API 23) and Android N (API 24) with all the tools in the extras.

Comment: move to Android Studio ^^

Comment: same suggestion as @Kurlicue. ADT plugin is not supported by Google. Try to migrate to Android Studio

Comment: @ Rafal : So, are you sure there would be no problem further if I switch to Android Studio with the above stated configuration of SDK?